# How can I filter data in json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've a external JSON file like this:

```
{"colors":[{
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "value": "#0f0"
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "value": "#00f"
    }]}
```

I want to filter data in order to obtain the name giving the value. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "./data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        success: function (json){
            $(json.colors).each(function(i,data){

                let key="value";
                let value="#00f";
                let result= data.filter(d=>d[key]==value);
                console.log(result)

            
            });
        }
    })
```

Obv it doesn't work. How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance to who will help me.

```js
const json = `{"colors":[{
  "color": "red",
  "value": "#f00"
},
{
  "color": "green",
  "value": "#0f0"
},
{
  "color": "blue",
  "value": "#00f"
}]}`;

function fakeAjax(options) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        options.success(JSON.parse(json));
    }, 800);
}

fakeAjax({
    url: "./data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (json){
        $(json.colors).each(function(i,data){
            let key="value";
            let value="#00f";
            let result= data.filter(d=>d[key]==value);
            console.log(result)


        });
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: note, the argument `json` isn't actually JSON, it's a plain ol' javascript object, so, you can do with it anything you can do with any Object in javascript

Comment: AJAX are for requests to distant servers, not to parse a local file. `import` or `require` your file, and `JSON.parse(file)` it.

Comment: what makes you think it's a local file? it's a file on the server that served the web page @GaëtanBoyals - do you not know how web request urls work? and you can't import a `.json` file in a browser, nor can you `require` any file in a browser - this isn't node.js

Comment: *"I've a external JSON file like this:"* That's invalid JSON. To be valid JSON, all of the property names must be in double quotes. So it may be that you're getting an error. You haven't included an error handler in your `ajax` call, so you may be missing it. (**Always** include an error handler. :-) )

Comment: @Bravo If it's a file that belongs to the same server requesting the file then, by definition, **it is** a local file.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals it's not local to the browser - and browsers can't import json files (unless something has changed recently) nor can they require anything (without the requirejs library at least), this is a browser, not nodejs - but thank you for the uncorrection

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals - I see what you're saing, but that's not the usual definition of "local." "Local" usually refers to where the code is running (the browser in this case), not the server. It's the same origin, but not *local*.

Comment: step one ... don't use $.each ... step two, use array `filter` method

Comment: @Bravo & T.J. Crowder Yeah, I didn't realize there weren't any NodeJS tags, I was just too quick to assume that this was attempted with Node. Lesson learned for the next questions!

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals - We've all done it! :-)

Comment: *“Obv it doesn't works.”* Could you describe what the current behaviour is, and the behaviour you're expecting? With your current code I would expect 3 `console.log`s of `[{ "color": "blue",  "value": "#00f" }]`. So your solution sort of works.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals ... FYI: jquery was the big clue that this is browser code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `each` callback, `data` is an object (each of the objects from `colors`), but you're trying to treat it like an array.

You seem to want to find the color with `value === "#00f"`. If so, you don't need that many layers of loops, you've already gone into the object to get the `colors` array, just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on it directly:

```
success: function (obj){ // chnaged name, it's not JSON
    const key = "value";
    const value = "#00f";
    const result = obj.colors.filter(color => color[key] === value);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Updated snippet:

```js
const json = `{"colors":[{
  "color": "red",
  "value": "#f00"
},
{
  "color": "green",
  "value": "#0f0"
},
{
  "color": "blue",
  "value": "#00f"
}]}`;

function fakeAjax(options) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        options.success(JSON.parse(json));
    }, 100);
}

fakeAjax({
    url: "./data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (obj){ // chnaged name, it's not JSON
        let key="value";
        let value="#00f";
        const result = obj.colors.filter(color => color[key] === value);
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you wanted just the first color object, not all matching color objects, you'd use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
success: function (obj){ // chnaged name, it's not JSON
    const key = "value";
    const value = "#00f";
    const result = obj.colors.find(color => color[key] === value);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Updated snippet:

```js
const json = `{"colors":[{
  "color": "red",
  "value": "#f00"
},
{
  "color": "green",
  "value": "#0f0"
},
{
  "color": "blue",
  "value": "#00f"
}]}`;

function fakeAjax(options) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        options.success(JSON.parse(json));
    }, 100);
}

fakeAjax({
    url: "./data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (obj){ // chnaged name, it's not JSON
        let key="value";
        let value="#00f";
        const result = obj.colors.find(color => color[key] === value);
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `data` is an object, `.filter` method will not work as it works only with arrays.

Working Demo in jQuery **:**

```js
// This is what you're receiving in your `success` callback
const json = {
    colors: [{
      color: "red",
      value: "#f00"
    },{
      color: "green",
      value: "#0f0"
    },{
      color: "blue",
      value: "#00f"
    }]
};

let key = "value";
let value = "#00f";

const result = $.makeArray(json.colors).filter((data) => data[key] === value);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `colors` is an array. Why are you running it through a function called `makeArray`?

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote - it's a little confusing with `data` as that's normally in the `success:` (but not in OPs case) and no need for `$.makeArray` (downvote before above comment).   Maybe make it closer to OPs original code (with `json.color`)

Comment: I took the liberty of **minimally** applying the change @freedomn-m suggested. I too suspect that your starting with the `colors` array instead of the `json` (sic) variable may have confused someone. I left the `$.makeArray` call to avoid conflicting with your intent, though like Quentin, it's unclear to me what that intent is. :-)